# Openfire Optimization Issues

Tags: openfire

I have found some optimisation issues in open-fire.

1. I am not using groups implementation, still below queries are getting fired.

   ```
   SELECT groupName FROM ofGroupUser WHERE username='?'.
   SELECT groupName from ofGroupProp WHERE ...
   ```
2. Every now and then these queries are fired off no reason

   ```
   SELECT offlinePresence, offlineDate FROM ofPresence WHERE username='?'
   SELECT DISTINCT serviceID FROM ofPubsubNode WHERE serviceID='?'
   ```

Also, documentation is very poor:

http://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database-guide.html

https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1673

I don't understand what all cache means. How can I save these queries?

Answer (score 0):

As Openfire is an Opensource project so documentation is also dependent on community contribution.

For your mentioned queries, if you are really looking for optimizations on this level, you should check out the source code of Openfire from Github and track the functionality which is firing these queries and if that looks unnecessary in your case, you can definitely customize those keeping in mind the side effects. There is no simple way to just stop/start such queries from configuration.